What option I can set for network request blocking in Safari using Selenium?
There is an option that I can set to avoid requests from specific url in Selenium (Java) for Chrome browser
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--host-resolver-rules=MAP www.googletagmanager.com 127.0.0.1");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

And what about Safari browser?
I am trying to get my Java auto tests avoiding some trafic from specific url.

you could just edit your HOSTS file to globally redirect certain domain names.  Looks like the above is doing same (redirecting www.googletagmanager.com to localhost)
